# Delete cache data of another app using Android code

Tags: android

```
Process p1;
p1=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf /sdcard/<any folder>");
```

This code works on sdcard, deleting the required folder, but not working on root directory

```
p1=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf /data/data/<any folder>");
```

This code is not working any suggestions?
i rooted my phone and got super user access.

Comment: App's `data/data/` directory is `Private` to that app. Other App **can not** access that files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to explicitly request superuser rights before deleting files:

```
String command = "rm -rf /";    // your command

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "su" );
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());

os.writeBytes(command + "\n");
os.writeBytes("exit\n");
os.flush();
```

also it's a good idea to wrap this in exception handler to handle various errors (no SU installed, wrong command, IOException, InterruptedException etc.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Access to `/sdcard` is not restricted. Any process can read or write to it. Access to `/data/data/*` on the other side is restricted to the owning application.
2. A rooted phone doesn't mean, that all your applications have root access. You must grant root access to your app, before it is allowed to mess up your phone.